# Proving the cofinite topology is in fact a topology.

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

So I am trying to prove the cofinite topology for a given space X is in fact a topology. I was able to follow this: http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-cofinite-topology but I have a problem with the part on arbitrary unions. If U_i is the empty set for some i, why is the intersection of (U_i)^c for all i's the empty set? If U_i is the empty set for some i, then the complement of this U_i will be X, the intersection of X with anything else will surely result in a subset of X, but why the empty set?

Comment: It isn't correct. We could have $U_i=\varnothing$ for all $i$, so that $U_i^c=X$ and $\bigcap_{i\in I}U_i=X$.

Comment: Notice however that if $U_i = \varnothing$, then $U_i^c = X$ is neutral (with respect to intersection), so you can ignore those.

Comment: (+1) You are right to suspect an error in these notes. I suggest you [report it](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/submit-an-error) to the author.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: @AnneBauval: The question is about the error on the linked page, not about how to correctly prove the result, so this isn't a duplicate of that question.

Comment: I know, therefore I upvoted your answer, but I wanted to avoid other answers to duplicate the correct proof. @joriki

Comment: @AnneBauval: OK; I was just trying to make sure that the question doesn't get closed as a duplicate. There are by now $3$ votes to close as a duplicate. (Note that close votes can be retracted, in case one of those is yours.)

Answer (score 1):

You’re right, that’s an error on the page you linked to.

Comment: @ℋolo the question (about the error on the linked page) was not a duplicate. The natural answer is this one, and not a duplicate of [a correct proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4158698/386889).